# Find subsequent occurrence of a value in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

I have a table which looks like shown below

```
ID    SubmittedValue      ApprovedValue
1     25.9                0
1     29                  29
1     25.9                25.9
1     50                  0
1     45                  0
1     10                  0
1     10                  10
```

**Expected result**

```
ID       SubsequentlyApproved(CNT)    Total_Amt_sub_aprvd
1        2                            35.9
```

We get the above result because 25.9+10 since it is repeated in the subsequent rows.

How to perform VLOOKUP like functionality for this scenario. I tried the subquery but it didn't work.

```
SELECT a.id,  
SUM(CASE WHEN a.ApprovedValue=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SUB_COUNT
FROM myTable a
join (select id, sum( case when SubmittedValue=ApprovedValue then 1 end) as check_value from myTable) b
on b.id=a.id and SUB_COUNT=check_value
```

but this is not giving me the expected result.

Comment: Why is the value not 3/64.9?

Comment: @GordonLinoff First value 25.9 was not approved so the value is 0 and it was approved in the third line. Similarly first time the value 10 was not approved so it is 0 and it was approved in the subsequent rows where submittedvalue and approved value=10 so we count these as 2 and 35.9

Comment: `in the consequent rows.` - there is no "subsequent row" in your example - the relational database system may return rows in any order unless the [ORDER BY clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_by) is specified. But this example does not contain any colum that defines the order.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to count rows where the values are the same and the first value appears more than once.  If so, you can use window functions and aggregation:

```
select id, count(*), sum(ApprovedValue)
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by id, SubmittedValue) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1 and SubmittedValue = ApprovedValue
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `window functions` using a `semi-join`

```
  select id, count(*), sum(submittedvalue)
  from test t1
  where submittedvalue=approvedvalue
  and exists (select 1 
              from test t2
              where t1.id=t2.id and t1.submittedvalue=t2.submittedvalue 
              group by id, submittedvalue 
              having count(*)>1)
  group by id;
```